# Why is my page still loading although my progress bar indicates that the upload is already completed?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an Uploader with progress bar:

index.php:

```
<h1>Uploader</h1>
<hr>
<form action="#">
  <input type="file" name="image">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger cancel">Cancel</button>
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width:0%"></div>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    uploadImage($form);
  });

  function uploadImage($form) {
    $form.find('.progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-success')
      .removeClass('progress-bar-danger');

    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //progress event...
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
      var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
      $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
    });

    //progress completed load event
    request.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
      $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completed....');
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
      };
      request.open("post", "upload.php");
      request.send(formdata);
    });

    request.open('post', 'upload.php');
    request.send(formdata);

    $form.on('click', '.cancel', function() {
      request.abort();

      $form.find('.progress-bar')
        .addClass('progress-bar-danger')
        .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
        .html('upload aborted...');
    });

  }
</script>
```

`upload.php`:

```
<?php
   $tmp_file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'files/'. $filename);

   echo "result";
   ?>
```

My problem is, that the loading time of the progress bar takes
 for example 10 seconds. Than I get the message "Upload completed" and
 then it takes again 10 seconds until the new page is loaded.

Comment: Is that jQuery? Why don't use native jQuery `$.ajax`? It's alot easier.

Comment: @Chay22 Thank you! Not sure how!

Comment: You should always make sure that you code is indented correctly, otherwise it is really hard to read and understand. This is not only important if you expect others to help you, but also for yourself to better understand your own code and to easier find errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two identical var declaration...
Try renaming the second request that is in the load listener.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

**EDIT:**

After a couple tries... It appeared that the second request is completely unusefull.

The resulting upload script:

```
function uploadImage($form){
    $form.find('.progress-bar').removeClass('progress-bar-success')
    .removeClass('progress-bar-danger');

    var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement
    $('#image').attr({ value: '' });            // <-- Removes the file from the input.
    var formdataWithoutFile = new FormData($form[0]);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //progress event...
    request.upload.addEventListener('progress',function(e){
        var percent = Math.round(e.loaded/e.total * 100);
        $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%').html(percent+'%');
    });

    //progress completed load event
    request.addEventListener('load',function(e){
        $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completed....');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }
    });

    request.open('post', 'upload.php');
    request.send(formdata);

    $form.on('click','.cancel',function(){
        request.abort();

        $form.find('.progress-bar')
        .addClass('progress-bar-danger')
        .removeClass('progress-bar-success')
        .html('upload aborted...');
    });
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, now the loader is going from 0% to 100% and then starts again and again endlessly

Comment: Maybe I should rename the second one?

Comment: Yes. try the renaming.

Comment: I tried to do it but still 10 seconds progress bar and after that 10 seconds until page loaded

Comment: I will test it! One moment

Comment: tested it, but the problem is still there :(

Comment: I edited again... With a new line to add in order to remove the file from formdata.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try

Comment: Where exactly do you mean to put $('#image').attr({ value: '' });  What is the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112921/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-jarla).

Comment: You replaced all `request` in the callback function with `requestChecking` so there is - because of the scoping - no difference to the original code.

Comment: @t.niese... You're right! lol. But it looks like the second request may not be necessary at all... I'm in chat with Jarla. Another edit will come for sure.